# Printing Array Items by Index Number in ImageJ (Fiji)

Tags: arrays, macros, imagej, imagej-macro, fiji

I'm trying to figure out how I can access an item in an array by it's index number.  I've written a script which will generate an array, with some number of variables.  There's an old script on the imageJ mailing list archive (shown below) which is able to print given index value for a known value within the array, but is there a way to find the value within the array itself?  I.e. if I have the user input the number of values that should be in the array, can I have the macro call up the values in the array from that?

My array generator:

```
Dialog.create("Time Point Input");
Dialog.addNumber("How many time points?", 0)
Dialog.addString("What are your time points (comma separated, no spaces)?:",0);
Dialog.show();
time = Dialog.getNumber();
points = Dialog.getString();
Fpoints = newArray(points);
```

Where the readouts could be something like:

```
time = 4
points = 5,10,12,27

Fpoints[0] = 5
Fpoints [1] = 10
Fpoints [2] = 12
Fpoints [3] = 27
```

Calling up index from array number value example code:

```
arr = newArray(1,5,3,12); 
i = index(arr, 5); 
print("index = "+i); 

  function index(a, value) { 
      for (i=0; i<a.length; i++) 
      if (a[i]==value) return i; 
  return -1; 
 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if I get your question right.

> but is there a way to find the value within the array itself?

The problem is that you cannot create an Array with `points` since it's a String. 
Try something linke:

```
Fpoints = split(points, ',');
```

Then you can iterate over Fpoints with a loop, or use you index function to get an index of a given value.

```
for (i = 0; i < Fpoints.length; i++) {
    print(Fpoints[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  The loop is what I was looking for.  I didn't realize that I had to split the string in order to be able to find the items in it by their index.  Iterating through the list is exactly what I needed to get the rest of the script to work.  I appreciate your help!